# Trying to return to previously faded html file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have a series of buttons on a main HTML file that fade out part of the HTML and fade in new HTML using Javascript, and the new HTML has a back button that I want to use to make the current HTML file fade out and fade in the main one but is not working.

These are my buttons:

```
<div id="buttons">
    <button id="button-job" class="button">FIND JOB</button>
    <button id="button-offers" class="button">OFFERS</button>
    <button id="button-save" class="button">SAVE</button>
</div>
```

Back button on another HTML:

```
<button id="button-back" class="button">BACK</button>
```

This is my Javascript:

```
$(function() {
  $("#profile1").load("profile.html");
  $("#button-job").click(function(){
      $("#profile1").fadeOut(1000,function(){
        $("#profile1").load("jobs.html");
        $("#profile1").fadeIn(1000);
      });
  });

  $("#button-offers").click(function(){
      $("#profile1").fadeOut(1000,function(){
        $("#profile1").load("offers.html");
        $("#profile1").fadeIn(1000);
      });
  });

  $("#button-back").click(function(){
    $("#profile1").fadeOut(1000,function(){
      $("#profile1").load("profile.html");
      $("#profile1").fadeIn(1000);
    });
  });

});
```

Comment: `#button-back` does not exist when you bind the click handler. Use event delegation:  `$("#profile1").on("click", "#button-back", function(){...`

Comment: @blex that worked like a charm thank you :)